# how can combine two columns in the same table and count its unique occurrences

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have been struggling and would really appreciate some assistance:

I have two tables cars and rides

```
cars 
car_id car_manuf  car_model
     1 Honda      CRV
     2 Honda      Accord
     3 Toyota     Corolla
     4 Toyota     Camry
     5 Ford       Fusion

rides
ride_id car_id ride_destination
      1      3 Boston
      2      5 New York
      3      5 Washington DC
      4      1 California
      5      2 Dallas
      6      5 Canada
```

I would like to count the number of rides by each car type which will have the combination of car_manuf and car_model and should be sorted from most to fewest number of rides.

Output should be:

```
CarType-NumberofRides
Honda_CRV-1
Honda_Accord-1
Toyota_Corolla-1
Toyota_Camry-0
Ford_Fusion-3
```

Sorted output with most-few rides

```
CarType-NumberofRides
Toyota_Camry-0
Honda_Accord-1
Toyota_Corolla-1
Honda_CRV-1
Ford_Fusion-3
```

mycode:

```
select
  c.car_manuf + '_' + c.car_model AS 'Car Type', 
  (select count(*) from rides r where r.car_id = c.car_id)  AS 'Number of Rides'
from cars c;
```

I am kinda stuck here and not sure which direction I should go in regards to getting the correct output.

Comment: Handle the formatting in your application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `GROUP BY` and an `ORDER BY` when `COUNT`ing the occurences. I use `CONCAT` to concatenate the strings instead of a + sign. Makes clearer what is going on, and is not mistaken as an arithmetic operation.

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.car_manuf, '_', c.car_model) AS CarType, COUNT(r.car_id) AS NumberOfRides
FROM rides r
LEFT JOIN cars c ON (r.car_id = c.car_id)
GROUP BY CarType
ORDER BY NumberOfRides ASC
```

However this omits the 0 occurences.

If you want to see the 0s as well swap the table order to:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.car_manuf, '_', c.car_model) AS CarType, COUNT(r.car_id) AS NumberOfRides
FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN rides r ON (r.car_id = c.car_id)
GROUP BY CarType
ORDER BY NumberOfRides ASC
```

Comment: How would I get the sum of the count of rides for each group of CarType? having "GROUP BY carType" puts all carTypes in each individual unique groups but does not add the total number of rides. For Example: I have the following output - CarType-NumberofRides - Toyota-Corolla-4, Toyota Corolla-5, Ford-Fusion-6, with "Group BY" the Output shows, Toyota-Corolla-4, Ford-Fusion-6. Instead it should output Toyota-Corolla-9, Ford-Fusion-6. How can I get that sum of rides to show?

Comment: It groups the same things together, in your example in the comment it seems that some of the stuff is slightly different worded (e.g. with and without a dash with the Toyota Corollas). If you have a chance, clean the data so you can group. Otherwise add an ID to differently named but intended to be same types and group by that. But that would be a new question